# zyBooks' "Seasons" Lab has me confused

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to do a zyBooks lab called "Seasons" for my Programming Fundamentals I course, and while the code I've come up with works for the first test input, it fails every other test. At this point I'm pretty sure I'm either failing to grasp something or I'm just making things more complicated than they need to be, but I've tried everything I can think of short of asking for help, so here we are.

Anyways, here's the code in question:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month == 'March' or 'April' or 'May' or 'June':
    if input_month == 'March':
        if 20 <= input_day <= 31:
            print('Spring')
    elif input_month == 'April' or 'May':
        print('Spring')
    elif input_month == 'June':
        if 0 < input_day <= 20:
            print('Spring')
elif input_month == 'June' or 'July' or 'August' or 'September':
    if input_month == 'June':
        if 21 <= input_day <= 30:
            print('Summer')
    elif input_month == 'July' or 'August':
        print('Summer')
    elif input_month == 'September':
        if 0 < input_day <= 21:
            print('Summer')
elif input_month == 'September' or 'October' or 'November' or 'December':
    if input_month == 'September':
        if 22 <= input_day <= 30:
            print('Autumn')
    elif input_month == 'October' or 'November':
        print('Autumn')
    elif input_month == 'December':
        if 0 < input_day <= 20:
            print('Autumn')
elif input_month == 'December' or 'January' or 'February' or 'March':
    if input_month == 'December':
        if 21 <= input_day <= 31:
            print('Winter')
    elif input_month == 'January' or 'February':
        print('Winter')
    elif input_month == 'March':
        if 0 < input_day <= 19:
            print('Winter')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

I've tried tweaking my code every way I can think of and in every combination I can think of to get it to return the *expected* result for each test, but no matter what, every test input invariably returns "Spring" (sans quotes, of course) as the output, and I don't understand why.

Comment: `input_month == 'March' or 'April' or 'May' or 'June'` doesn't do what you think it should do.